# LinkedIn API not returning SSL images for Group Posts and Company Shares

Tags: image, ssl, share, linkedin-api

A trick that works fine to get user's profile picture-url is to add the **secure=true** param.

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url;secure=true,public-profile-url,id)
```

This is not working for most of the images. Some examples are:

- Company **'logo-url'** and **'square-logo-url'**
- Company status update **'submitted-image-url'**
- Group **'small-logo-url'** and **'large-logo-url'**
- Group post attachment **'image-url'**

Is there any workaround to get a secure image in those cases?

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn API returning secure images for profile only(secure=true) now 
 for company,group etc not have any mechanism for getting secure image